Can't see webservice namespace in aspx.cs
I work on a solution that has many projects.
Two of them are: ABCD.WebSite and ABCD.WebServices.
The way ABCD.WebSite uses ABCD.WebServices is not quite familiar to me.
ABCD.WebServices is added to ABCD.WebSite per 'add reference', not 'add service reference'
Then ABCD.WebSite has 'services' folder, which contains files named like 'GeoMappingService.svc'
Full content of such file:
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ABCD.WebServices.GeoMappingService"  %>

Endpoints are defined in web.config.
Interface for service, ABCD.WebServices.IGeoMappingService.cs
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GeoMappingService")] void
GeoMappingService();

Everything works fine, I get service's operations list (WSDL and JSON), can call them and get result.
In global.asax, Application_Start, I get ABC.WebServices namespace and can use GeoMappingService.
But when I add an aspx form to ABCD.WebSite, like GeoMapping.aspx - ABCD.WebServices namespace is not available.
How can I use it in aspx file?
